# Make checkbox input 1 or 0 into form in acrobat

Tags: forms, checkbox, acrobat

I need to be able to make a checkbox in a form in Acrobat return a 0 if checked and a 1 if not check into another text box or form in acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox on tick will return NULL or "" and on unchecking it will return "Off" in Acrobat so you can right javascript as

```
if(this.getField("Checkboxid").value!="Off")
{
    this.getField("textboxid").value=1
}
else
{
   this.getField("textboxid").value=0
}
```

we can right this **javascript** on **checkbox** *"Mouse Up" event*.